# Doesn't show proper image when click on link

Tags: php, mysql, image

On my home page I have one image(big) on left side and small box in my right panel where I show random thumb of images on every refresh page. Here is how I show this image:

```
$rand = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from images order by RAND() LIMIT 0,1");
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rand))
{
  echo "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"upload/".$res['name']."\" /><br />";
  echo "<div id=\"caption\" style=\"text-align:center;\">".$res['caption']."</div><br />";
  echo "<a href=pics.php?id=".$res['id'].">Open in new page &raquo</a>";
}
```

How to make when someone click on thumb to open that image in new page? This `echo "<a href=pics.php?id=".$res['id'].">Open in new window &raquo</a>";` doesn't open the proper image. In fact just refreshing the page but the image is the same.

UPDATE:
pics.php

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images";
            $result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
            $r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $numrows = $r[0];

            $rowsperpage = 1;
            $totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

            if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
                $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
            } else {
                $currentpage = 1;
            }
            if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
                $currentpage = $totalpages;
            } // end if
            if ($currentpage < 1) {
                $currentpage = 1;
            } // end if

            $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;
$sql = "SELECT name, caption FROM images LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
    while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<div id=\"picture\">";
    echo "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"upload/".$list['name']."\" /></a><br />";
    echo "<div id=\"caption\">".$list['caption']."</div><br />";
} // end while
```

Comment: Does the correct URL open when you click the link?

Comment: Always quote your HTML attributes! `...<a href='pics.php?id=".$res['id']."'>...`

Comment: And inspect the page source in your browser. Does the rendered `<a href...` look like you expect it to?

Comment: The correct ID is loaded in URL but the image not. The image is the same as before click.. this on the left side of page (big image)..

Comment: Show the code from pics.php where you display the image please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First there is no need to put `LIMIT 0,1` Just have

```
$rand = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from images order by RAND() LIMIT 1");
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rand);

  echo "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"upload/".$res['name']."\" /><br   />";
  echo "<div id=\"caption\" style=\"text-align:center;\">".$res['caption']."</div><br />";
  echo "<a href=pics.php?id=".$res['id'].">Open in new page &raquo</a>";
```

And in you pics.php you must specify the id of the image in your sql query

```
$id = abs((int)$_GET['id']);
$sql = "SELECT name, caption FROM images WHERE id='{$id}'  LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo "<div id=\"picture\">";
echo "<img style=\"width:100%;margin:0 auto;\" src=\"upload/".$list['name']."\" /></a><br />";
echo "<div id=\"caption\">".$list['caption']."</div><br />";
} // end while
```

Comment: Just an question. What is ...abs.. in `abs((int)$_GET['id']);`?